# Bug in Google Pagespeed?

Tags: google-pagespeed

My site in Google Pagespeed gives 84 points.
It says I can improve by adding browser cache headers.
When I do this (Expires, E-Tag, ...) I get only 81 points and it still says I should add browser caching headers although it says content IS cached (5 Minutes).

[image]

I don't understand why it lowers the rating although I implemented the suggested fixes.

Why is this or what might I be doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Page Speed likes to see files cached for a week or more. If you want the points, you could increase the cache time to have a max-age of **604800**.